# NodeJS Splitting input into multiple strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, split

Taking input from a user that would be:

```
!timeout 60 username reason
```

!timeout, 60, and username will never have spaces, but it can be assumed that reason will usually have spaces.

I'd hope to end up with:

```
var1 = "!timeout"
var2 = 60
var3 = "username"
var4 = "reason"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time-saving nirvana, I'd probably use a simple [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and some presumptuous array access:

```js
var test = "!timeout 60 username reason and then some";

var chunks = test.split(" ");

var timeout = chunks[0];
var time = chunks[1];
var username = chunks[2];
var reason = chunks.slice(3).join(' ');

console.log(timeout, '|', time, '|', username, '|', reason);
```

Or a nice little one-liner:

```js
var test = "!timeout 60 username reason and then some";

var result = test.split(" ", 3).concat(test.split(" ").slice(3).join(' '));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why bother with a regex that contains just a space?  You can just pass `" "`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Very true. Probably because I was going to try and find some catch-all regex at first. Will update the answer with just `" "`.

Comment: Or only split once: `(function(s) {return s.slice(0, 3).concat(s.slice(3).join(" "));})(test.split(" "));`

Comment: @Jason Yep. Though aesthetically I find it uglier.

Comment: And your one-liner isn't an eyesore? ;)

Comment: @Jason It's that little bit prettier without the squigglies. :-) I'm not sure I like the idea of creating and dumping anonymous scopes in the same breath too... But I can see value in the approach.